# In SF Marketing Cloud Journey Builder - can email send times be scheduled?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is it possible to time the initial deployment of an email in Journey Builder?

Will the journey kick off with the delivery of the data set or will there be a wait time?  I understand that the subsequent email deployments of the Journey can't necessarily be times - I'm assuming they are keyed to the initial start time of the  journey.

Answer (score 5):

You can use wait time activity to schedule your email sends. After the entry source you can use 'Wait by duration' activity (this will let you set wait time in Minutes/Hours/Days/Weeks/Months) if you have scheduled your journey for a particular day and time and you know after how much time the email should go out.

You can also use 'Wait until Date' activity which will let you specify the Date, time and timezone in which you want to schedule your email to be sent to contacts.

[image]

I hope I understood your question correctly because it is framed a bit complexly.

Update: Adding a snapshot of "Wait until date" activity
[image]

Comment: Wait by attribute also lets you control for each individual record the date/time it goes out based on a value inside the Journey Data or Contact Data. Which is super helpful for STO uses.

Comment: You did.  sorry about the complexity - totally due to my lack of familiarity.

Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Krati - My apologies but - a follow up question. What is the timing of the send on the the "wait until date" option and can it be governed?   So, can the date AND time be set?

Comment: Hi @dfqueally42 You can set the date and time if you use "wait until date' option. In that case, the journey will wait until that date and time and once that time is reached, the contact will receive the email(if that's the next step that you have put in your journey). I have updated my answer with a snapshot of the Wait activity. And yes, you can govern the wait activity by checking history of that journey. It will show you where the contact is present at a specific time.

Comment: Awesome ... thanks so much for the advice.